# Read kinesis records using startsequencenumber and endsequencenumber in the SQS Event of failure

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I have a `lambda` which has `eventsource` as `KDS`. Since `Lambda` receives the `KDS` records as a `batch`, I have implemented the `StreamEventResponse` mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-batchfailurereporting) to return the failed record for `retry`. After retries are exhausted I am sending the failed records to `SQS` as failure destination.

Now as per the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-errors), only the metadata of the `kdsbatch` is sent to SQS. So I am trying to fetch KDS details using `shardId` and `sequencenumber` details mentioned in the `SQSEvent`. Lets say in a batch of records with sequencenumbers `A,B,C,D`, `B and C` records `fail` and are sent to SQS. SQSEvent will have 2 records each with `startsequencenumber=A` and `endsequencenumber=D`. Now how do I find out records `B and C` from KDS since I dont have their sequencenumber in the SQSEvent in the first place. I only have start and end sequence numbers of the entire batch.

**Below is Example SQS Event**

```
{
    "requestContext": {
        "requestId": "c9b8fa9f-5a7f-xmpl-af9c-0c604cde93a5",
        "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:myfunction",
        "condition": "RetryAttemptsExhausted",
        "approximateInvokeCount": 1
    },
    "responseContext": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "executedVersion": "$LATEST",
        "functionError": "Unhandled"
    },
    "version": "1.0",
    "timestamp": "2019-11-14T00:38:06.021Z",
    "KinesisBatchInfo": {
        "shardId": "shardId-000000000001",
        "startSequenceNumber": "A",
        "endSequenceNumber": "D",
        "approximateArrivalOfFirstRecord": "2019-11-14T00:38:04.835Z",
        "approximateArrivalOfLastRecord": "2019-11-14T00:38:05.580Z",
        "batchSize": 4,
        "streamArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-2:123456789012:stream/mystream"
    }
}
```